# "scanning use of \frame" and "environment undefined"

Tags: beamer, overlays

I added an overlay to a frame and my beamer file started giving my trouble with the two frames that I cut and paste below. More precisely:

If I let the two frames in the text and compile, the error is "file ended while scanning use of \frame"
If I take out only the second frame, it happen the same.
If I take out only the first frame, the mistake is "environment undefined", and the line number corresponding to the last line of the second frame shows up.

I really don't know what to do. I am not a very skilful beamer/latex guy, but the frames are very basic, and I can't see any mistake in them.

If you have time to help me out, I would be forever grateful.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{colourchange}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%[<+->]
\frametitle{How do Experience and Metaphysics relate to each other?}

\begin{itemize}

\item<2-> Experience does not distinguish between the A- and the B-theory
\item<3-> Experience is \textit{compatible} with the A-theory, the B-theory\ldots
\item<4-> \ldots Berkelyan idealism, Cartesian skeptics, Russellian skeptics\ldots
\item<5-> \ldots Hyper-Russellian skeptics: 


\begin<itemize>
\item<6->{only one conscious experience exists (and it is indistinguishable from \textit{this} experience that \textit{you} are having \textit{now})
\end{itemize}

\item<7-> Yet, it does not follow that experience cannot support better a metaphysical theory over a competing one: \only<9->{All your experiences exists \textit{vs.} hyper-Russellian skeptics}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------


\begin{frame}%[<+->]
\frametitle{An Abductive Argument for the A-theory}


\begin<itemize>
\item<2-> Different claim: ``Experience \textit{better supports} the A-theory''

\begin{enumerate}
\item<3-> Our experience has $E_T$
\item<4-> The thesis $A_1$ that the passage of time is an objective, mind-independent fact is an essential part of our best explanation of why our experience has $E_T$
\item<5-> \textbf{The A-theory is true}
\end{enumerate}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A new Italian fellow, hurray! Please, add some code to make the example compilable.

Comment: To compile, it needs to start with `documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. I can't compile frames on their own... ;)

Comment: Thanks. I added it by editing the post, although I did not manage to get it inside the code window. Sorry.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Missed the bits outside the frame.

Comment: I was adding them while you were writing, I guess :)

Comment: You have `\mode<presentation> {` but never close the curly brackets.

Comment: You have a missing closing brace after `\textit{you} are having \textit{now})` and two instances of `\begin<itemize>` that should be `\begin{itemize}`. I added also a closing brace for `\mode<presentation>` (copy paste error, I presume).

Comment: More importantly: a philosopher, hurray!

Comment: You are my angels. Thanks really I lot! I blush for the stupid mistakes I made, I am usually better than this ;) but I am a bit exhausted these days. Thanks again! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Localizing errors in a `beamer` document can be hard, because a missing brace is usually caught too late.

It helps having a “galley” document with the same preamble as the main one, where one frame is prepared at a time, then pasted to the main one when it compiles properly.

In your case you have a missing brace:

```
\begin<itemize>
\item<6->{only one conscious experience exists (and it is indistinguishable from \textit{this} experience that \textit{you} are having \textit{now})
\end{itemize}
```

should be

```
\begin<itemize>
\item<6->{only one conscious experience exists (and it is indistinguishable from \textit{this} experience that \textit{you} are having \textit{now})}
\end{itemize}
```

You also have two typos:

```
\begin<itemize>
```

should of course be

```
\begin{itemize}
```

(two places).